# Usage of HACK and UNDONE comment tags

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, documentation, tags

Many software engineers are familiar with the usage of special comment “tags” that can be added to their code comments, for use in searches, automated task tracking, and so forth.  Some of the most popular are FIXME, TODO, UNDONE, and HACK.

I'm a bit confused with the usage of HACK and UNDONE tags. Little help please?

*Bonus points for showing the basic difference between FIXME and TODO*

Comment: Personally my favorite is NOTHINGTOSEEHERE.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My understanding:

- TODO: Something that needs to be done. This could be a feature to be added later, or indicating that something is a stub and needs to be implemented.
- FIXME: A subclass of the TODO tag, indicating something is *broken* that needs to be *fixed*.
- UNDONE: A note to indicate a change which was a rollback or reversal of some other change. This comment will usually indicate what was removed and why.
- HACK: Something, usually an odd or unorthadox piece of code, which was added to fix some particular problem. These are usually not "elegant" solutions but nevertheless make the darn thing work. Often you will see these to address a bug in the framework or other unexpected behavior. Additionally, the purpose of the commented code will often be unclear were it not for the comment.

Comment: for what you describe it should be `UNDO` or `TOUNDO`. just google `define undone` and see what is popular: _not done or finished._

Answer (score 1):

UNDONE to me means that the method is not finished, it usually returns the data type despite no internal code

i wanted to say this because some people consider it a reversal, i would not pollute the code with these sorts of comments and have a feeling that many other people might use UNDONE to mean the same as me

it's a liberal ruleset but it's a great system

```
public int SomeCalculation(int Input)
{
  return 0; //UNDONE
}

public bool SomeCheck()
{
  return false; //UNDONE
}
```

Comment: That is another interpretation of the verb, but why not just use TODO. Then there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Difference between UNDONE and TODO is that UNDONE is more like work in progress and should not be touched by another dev and TODO is not yet started and more free to be picked up by another dev.